# How to send the toast push notification in windows phone 8 using azure mobile services

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, mpns

Created a free account on azure mobile services for testing the push notification to windows phone 8. Created a "Registrations" table and able to store the device id and uri channel name.

But unable to send the notification to device. Please guide how to send the toast notification  to windows phone 8 device using the registration table.

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: have you follwed these steps ? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-phone-get-started/

Comment: tried it but not success... unable to get toast message in emulator \ device.